# How to run ROS commands from C++ application?

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Original Author) want(s) to run ROS commands, like e.g. $ ROSCORE, from a C++ application. The following example does not work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>   
int main()    
{    
    system("/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/roscore");  
    return 0;    
}
```

Execution results in the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in <module>    
    from ros import roslaunch    
ImportError: No module named ros
```

Original Author was using Ubuntu 10.04.
Original Author notes that roscore successfully launches the master when executed from the command line

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10023/how-to-run-ros-commands-from-c++-application?/) by [ASMIK2011ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/352/asmik2011ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2011-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-08-06**:
I accidentally pushed this to the top by correcting the formatting. :P

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2013-12-18**:
you must use system("/opt/ros/diamondback/bin/roscore");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it is a problem with missing environment variables (python path?). You could try to run bash with the command as parameter, e.g. something like `bash -i -c "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/roscore"`. -i makes the bash read ~/.bashrc where I assume you source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.sh.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do you want to launch this from inside a program? If you include your program in a [launch file](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML) the roscore will also be launched.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3